# Please recommend a textbook for first-time learning Linear Algebra like Stewart's Calculus?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm trying to learn linear algebra on my own. When I taught myself calculus I-III a year ago, I used Stewart's *Concepts and Contexts* 4th edition and I absolutely loved it. Theorems and definitions were displayed clearly, the graphs were detailed, and the problem selection was quite large.

Is there a linear algebra textbook similar to how Stewart's textbook was designed?

Additionally, I'm eventually planning to learn differential equations and I'm aware that quite a few texts overlap when teaching these topics. I'd prefer to learn them individually, so I'd like to avoid texts with a good amount of differential equation, unless there is a text that covers both fields completely  in the same way that Stewart's text covered single and multivariable calculus together.

P.S I don't mean to be praising Stewart's. It's the only mathematics textbook I've used to self-study so I don't have much else to relate to.

Comment: I'd recommend Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel and Spence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the closest contender is David Lay's *Linear Algebra and its Applications*.

The material is presented in an approachable way.  The text is neither terse nor overly expository.  It is made clear exactly what the important pieces are, with true/false questions in the exercises to ensure you're paying attention.  He strikes a good balance between emphasizing matrices and emphasizing the underlying vector space structures.

That being said, the textbook (like Stewarts') is not perfect.  Lay tends to emphasize row reduction a bit more than I'd like, and emphasizes computational (as opposed to proof oriented) questions a bit much for my taste.  However, you can do much worse than Lay for an introduction.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend Gilbert Strang's book  "Introduction to linear algebra ". This book is just a joy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Ron Larson's [*Elementary Linear Algebra*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1305658000)

Ron Larson's *Calculus* textbook has the same beginner-friendly approach as Stewart's, so Larson's linear algebra textbook should be what someone like you may be looking for.